# How can I create an instance of type dynamically in Java

Tags: java, dynamic-typing

In my Java application I have method

```
public <T extends Transaction> boolean appendTransaction(T transaction) {
   ...
}
```

and inside of this method I need to create an instance of object **T** which extends **Transaction**

Is it correct to do it in this way

```
T newTransaction = (T) transaction.getClass().newInstance();
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you should use a factory-interface of type T, that way you can force a create-instance interface on the method-user.

```
public <T extends Transaction> boolean appendTransaction(
        T transaction, 
        Factory<T> factory) {
    ...
    T newTransaction = factory.createTransaction();
    ...
}
```

Comment: I sorta agree with you here. It's definitely cleaner and less magical.

Answer (score 2):

More or less, except that [`Class.newInstance`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) is evil:

> Note that this method propagates any exception thrown by the nullary constructor, including a checked exception. Use of this method effectively bypasses the compile-time exception checking that would otherwise be performed by the compiler.

Use [`transaction.getClass().getConstructor().newInstance()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Object...%29) instead, it wraps exceptions thrown in the constructor with an [`InvocationTargetException`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationTargetException.html).

Comment: Is more evil then just an alias for getConstructor().newInstance() ?

Comment: I updated with a motivation. It magically rethrows any exceptions thrown by the default constructor, even checked exceptions which you then can't catch explicitly (because `Class.newInstance` doesn't declare them in its signature).